# Conversion loses qualifiers, but doesn't really

Tags: c++, constants

This is somewhat related, but also bit different to: [C++ "conversion loses qualifiers" compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257219/c-conversion-loses-qualifiers-compile-error)

In my code I'm getting following error:

> error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const git_commit
>   *const *' to 'const git_commit **'

As much as I understand that assigning from T** to const T** would allow to violate rules of constness, here in the example I gave, that is, assigning from const T*const * to const T** actually gains constness, without loosing any, so where/why this is a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const git_commit * const *
```

a pointer to a constant array of pointers to constant git_commits

```
const git_commit * *
```

a pointer to a mutable array of pointers to constant git_commits

assigning a const array to a mutable array loses const.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I think I do understand, one thing though, your interpretation is slightly incorrect in the way that you are using word 'array', where in fact there isn't guarantee that there is any array. First one should be read as: pointer to const pointer to const object. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: Not quite... A pointer to a pointer is not a pointer to an array of pointers (that would be `***`, and being a [three-star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) is discouraged). If anything it might be a pointer to an array of `git_commit` objects. Or a "2d" array of `git_commit` objects.

Answer (score -1):

```
int const x = 7;
std::cout << x << '\n'; // compiler can optimize to 7
int const* const px = &x;
std::cout << *px << '\n'; // compiler can optimize to 7

int const*const* ppx = &px;
std::cout << **ppx << '\n'; // compiler can optimize to 7

int const** ppx_cheat = ppx; // illegal, but presume we are allowed to do it
int const y = 1;
int const* py = &y;
*ppx_cheat = py;
std::cout << **ppx << '\n'; // compiler can optimize to 7, *but is wrong*
```

Comment: That's not what's happening here. OP has a bog standard illegal `const T*` to `T*` conversion. (I made the same mistake at first)

Comment: @light you sure?  The error generated above matches the OP's no?

Comment: No it matches what I said

Comment: @light `error: invalid conversion from 'const int* const*' to 'const int**' [-fpermissive]` In what way does this not match the OP's error message?  I mean other than `int` being a different type.  Because that is the error my code above generates.  And which I explain.  Please be specific, not "no, I am right", because I have considered what I can gather of your position assuming you are right, and I cannot reconcile it.  I think I know what error you think I made, but I cannot tell as you are not being specific enough.